# Why is this error always gets called when i run react-native application?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

```
babelHelpers.inherits = function (subClass, superClass) {
if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) {
throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass);
}

subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, {
constructor: {
  value: subClass,
  enumerable: false,
  writable: true,
  configurable: true
}
});
if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass,superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass;
};
```

i know this is the error code which is being executed in my application. But i want to know why this error always being called? Do there any problem in initializing constructor or calling super() method, OR is there problem in importing different modules?? Please provide some suggestions.

Comment: Maybe an example of the code producing this error would help?

Comment: i dont get you. what are you talking about?

Comment: You're referencing an error... can you post your code that is triggering the error, or at least the error message is saying the cause of the error is.